# Tips for golfing in Thue

Tags: code-golf, tips

Anyone got tips for golfing in [Thue](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Thue). One tip per answer, and no tips aplicable to all languages (like remove comments)

Comment: Thue is basically /// but you can't make substitutions as a result of other substitutions, and also it's non-deterministic.